# Javascript: Linked List: Unable to delete object reference

Tags: javascript, oop, linked-list

I'm doing a Linked List data structure. The prototype includes a method to pop (delete) the last item from the list which I'm attempting to do by finding the last object, and then setting it to `null`. It does not seem to work. What does work is setting the reference (the 'pointer') in the previous object to `null`. I'm still a relative JS OOP newbie, can't get my brain to understand why. The code:

```
function LinkedList() {
    this._rootNode = null;
    this._length = 0;                                       
}

LinkedList.prototype = {

   push: function(data) {
       var newNode = {
           data: data,                                      
           nextNode: null
       };
       // initialize this._rootNode or subsequent .nextNode with newNode
       this._length++;
   },

   pop: function() {
       var selectedNode, perviousNode;

       if ( this._rootNode ) {
           if ( this._length > 1 ) {
               selectedNode = this._rootNode;
               while ( selectedNode.nextNode ) {
                   previousNode = selectedNode;  // <-- shouldn't need this?
                   selectedNode = selectedNode.nextNode;
               }
               selectedNode = null;              // <-- doesn't delete it
               // previousNode.nextNode = null;  // <-- works (but feels unnecessary?)
           } else {  
               this._rootNode = null;
           }
           this._length--;
       }
   },

   // more methods..
};


/* --- Main Prorgam --- */

var list = new LinkedList();

list.push('AAA');
list.push('BBB');
list.pop();
console.log(list._rootNode.nextNode.data);   <-- 'BBB' still there
```

Would appreciate some insight, and any other tips on improving the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you realize that your `push` method doesn't work, but you haven't asked about that one.

If you are doing some kind of school project that requires you to write a linked list like this, then by all means, continue.  Your issue is that `selectedNode` is not really "the node itself", it's a reference to it, and you're just setting that reference to null while the previous item's `nextNode` pointer still refers to it, so you haven't actually removed it from your list.  You would actually do so by un-commenting the line setting that pointer to null, which means you also have to leave in the line saving the reference to the previous node.

```
previousNode.nextNode = null;
```

You actually don't want to delete the node entirely with `pop()`, you want to return it.  Once you remove the reference to the popped node in your calling function though, it will be the last reference and the object will be made available for garbage collection.  This is (to my knowledge) how all traditional OOP languages handle linked lists at the basic level.

Which brings me to my next point, that most OOP languages you'll use these days don't actually require you to work on the basic level.  Most of them have libraries that will implement linked lists for you and Javascript in particular essentially implements a linked list-style data structure in its array syntax.  To the point where `([1,2,3,4]).pop()` evaluates to `4` and `([1,2,3,4]).push(5)` evaluates to `[1,2,3,4,5]`.  If you actually need to USE a linked list in a real project, just don't.

Comment: Ah, makes total sense! Yes, it is a programming exercise in data structures and algorithms, just tried whipping it out for fun. Thanks!

Comment: It would actually be quicker for you to `push` and `pop` from the front of the list.  Saves you the need to traverse it.  Just save a reference to the `rootNode`, set the `rootNode` reference to its `nextNode`, set the original node's `nextNode` reference to null and return it.  Same for push.  The only reason you'd need to traverse the list would be if you wanted to enforce a queue instead of a stack behavior.